# Rounding the number within two digits after the comma with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a product to add into the store, where there are two `input` fields `priceBase` and `priceFinal`. First is without TAX, second is with TAX.

While using this javascript function:

```
jQuery(function($){

    var priceBase = $('input[name="mprices[basePrice][]"]', '#productPriceBody');
    var priceFinal = $('input[name="mprices[salesPrice][]"]', '#productPriceBody');
    var priceDiff = priceFinal.val() - priceBase.val();
    var priceTax = priceDiff / priceBase.val();


    alert(priceFinal.val()); // 1.40004
    alert(priceBase.val());  // 1.16667
    alert(priceDiff);        // 0.23333399999999993
    alert(priceTax);         // 0.19999999999999993

});
```

How I suppose to round a `priceTax` value from `0.19999999999999993` to `0.20` ? Like normal math calculation you know, if it's 4 and below, it rounds to lower, if it's 5 it rounds to higher number.

Thanks for suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to want

```
alert(priceDiff.toFixed(2));
```

But you should parse the values before you do maths. It works here because you're lucky :

```
"33"-"12" => "21"
"33"+"12" => "3312"
```

So to avoid bugs in the future (when you use `+` instead of `-` for example) I'd suggest to always parse the field values :

```
var priceDiff = parseFloat(priceFinal.val()) - parseFloat(priceBase.val());
```